# html video won't play on iPad/iPhone

Tags: html, iphone, ipad, video-streaming, html5-video

I've spent too many hours trying to fix that issue.
This code works just fine in desktop:

```
 <video id="myVideo"  controls="true" >
    <source src="<spring:url value="/img/irewindIphone.mp4"/> " >
 </video>
```

I've removed width, type, auto-play to narrow down the possible causes.

The problem is on iPad and iPhone where only a cut play image appears on a black background.
I've converted the video to be supported by iPad or iPhone:

- Video Format: MP4, MOV, M4V
- Video Size: up to 640x480
- Video Framerate: up to 30fps
- Video Bitrate: up to 1.5Mbps for H.264, or 2.5Mbps for MPEG-4
- Audio: AAC up to 160Kbps, 48kHz

No luck.

I don't know what else I could do.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I found [this](https://discussions.apple.com/message/15453594#15453594) post and their answer indicates an environment problem. I run my web app on local host and connect to my IP so it can't be that.

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52201179/1889652) answer with the same issue I think it would help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues. If you are using safari , you need to install QuickTime player. If you use Opera Mini, there is nothing we can help you. [Other browser](http://caniuse.com/#search=video) supports video tag properly. But PC version of opera needs .ogg format.

Comment: So you are saying that on Safari it works with Quick Time player? I've tested this problem both in Chrome and Safari with same result. You are right, only .ogg video formats works in Opera for desktop.

Comment: Yes. I had no QuickTime player. When i started to test my website on Safari, video tag was not supported. But then it was fixed, when i installed player .