# how to play html5 video embedded in webpage on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, html5-video, embed

(sorry for the big images not sure how to resize in this markdown deriv)

I have some video in a webpage, using html5 video tag.
On android, the video will remain inline on the page, allowing me to have other content around it such as subtitles in the HTML.

But on the iPhone when you hit play the video jumps out full-screen, destroying any other features.

Is there any way to prevent this take-over?

On Android, or normal web, we don't have this problem.

FYI tags using are (jade)

```
  video(width="100%" controls="controls" autoplay="true" id='videoPlayer' class='video-player')
    source(src="#{videoUrl}" type="video/mp4")
```

### Before play

[image]

### After click to play

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While not originally possible in Safari on iOS using the native HTML `<video>` tag, Apple [finally added support for this](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/) a while back by adding support for specifying a `playsinline` attribute on video elements.

e.g. `<video … playsinline />`

I appreciate this question is old, but someone had down voted it and it was unanswered.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer! Moved on from that project awhile ago, but I will put this knowhow into my piggy bank for a rainy day.

Comment: You welcome! I remember being dismayed by not being able to do this and missed they rolled it out until I started seeing this behaviour on pages more. This was the first hit on Google for my query and can't believe it didn't have an answer already. Hopefully answering now will commit it to memory and save me having to look it up again myself. 8)